# ModX Revolution TV Access Permissions not working as expected

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I'm having difficulty getting the access permissions set on a Template Variable in ModX Revolution. I'm a member of the Administrators group, which has full access to the Admin resource group. However, whenever I set my template variable to allow only Admin access I can then no longer see the TV when I try to edit a page which uses the template the TV is used in.

Furthermore, I seem to have access to the TV whenever another resource group is allowed access to it. ModX seems to be allowing/denying access inverted to what it should.

I'm new to ModX and would really appreciate any help regarding this issue. I can post more information if required also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the access on the TV in the "access permissions" tab of the TV when you create or edit the TV?

I'm pretty sure you will have to add the administrator to the access group you are trying to restrict the TV to...